# Is there an Amarok scope for the music lens?

Tags: lenses, amarok, scopes

I'm searching for an amarok scope for the music lens for a while now but could not find anything, not even a project. Anybody got something working?

I use amarok as i love the dynamic play lists and so on, rhythmbox or clementine is nowhere near.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None exists as of yet. But you could [easily write one!](http://mhall119.com/2012/01/simplified-unity-lens-development-with-singlet/)

Comment: well that's always an option and probably what i will do if there is nothing ready yet. Will check out your articel!

Comment: It's really quite easy, even if you don't know how to program, Python is quite beginner friendly; hop into a tutorial.

Comment: No problem i can program but did not use python for quite some time (usually coding for windows) Thx